# element dimensions differ in chrome dev-tools from those set in css

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, height, width, dimensions

When I set a div-width of 200px and height of 200px in my css file, chrome dev-tools show those dimensions way smaller (about 150px x 150px) regarding the rulers.
[div set width: 200px; height: 200px;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnqbU.png)

I've also set:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

What is, I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!

Maybe will help someone. Very easy. It seems to be a bug in chrome dev tools. Just switch on/off the dev tools while in your chosen screen device and the dimensions set in the css file will show up properly.